# Can you use a array reference de the incrementor of a for loop

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I have this code but when I run it it just gives me a `NullPointerException`

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class System {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many planets"));
    Planet p[]=new Planet[a];
    for (int i=1;i<=a;i++){
        ** p[i].setName("romain"); **
                    //line bugging is above
    }
    //for info the .setName method of the Planet class is
     /*public void setName(String Na){
     name=Na;
 }*/

}

}
```

So my question is: can you use the incrementor as the array reference

Comment: can you start your loop at 0 instead of 1?

Comment: What is the full error that it gives?

Answer (score 1):

You have not initialized any of your `Planet` references. That's why you are getting a NullPointerException.

`Planet p[]=new Planet[a]` creates an array of `Planet` references, but the contents are all initialised to null. You need to have something like this:

```
Planet p[] = new Planet[a];
for (int i = 0; i < a; ++i) {
    p[i] = new Planet();
    p[i].setName("whatever");
}
```

Yes, you can use your loop variable to index into the array. You can use the loop variable for whatever you want: it's just an ordinary variable that happens to be scoped to the loop.

Note that in Java arrays are always zero-based, not one-based. The first element is at index zero.

Comment: Thank you so much, I wasn't expecting such a promt reply.

Comment: I started at 1 because my program will have a GUI and people will accept "planet 1" better than planet 0

Answer (score 0):

Your array doesn't say it's going to start at index 1 and it's not initialized to start at 1. Given your input style, you are setting number of plants as the array length.

start your loop at 0.

```
int a=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many planets"));
    Planet p[]=new Planet[a];
    for (int i=0;i<a;i++)
    {
//    -------------------------------------------------------------------
            p[i] = new Planet();       // initializing object reference
//    -------------------------------------------------------------------
        p[i].setName("romain");
    }
```

**EDITTED**
**THE QUESTION CONTENTS ARE EXPLAINED IN COMMENTS**

Comment: That's not what is causing the NPE.

Comment: My answer simply saying, since he is not explicitly initialized his array to 1-base, the array is going to start at zero base by default. :) You have further explained.

Comment: There's no way to have a 1-based array in Java. They are all zero-based. You can leave the first element `null` if you like, but the array itself is still zero-based.

Comment: I am not opposing to what you say. Perhaps the articulation in my answer/comments is not so satisfactory to you. Zero-based indexing is a constant annoyance of Java's zero-based indexing. We all know that. That's why by default it's 0-indexed. The natural human values are starting at 1 index and to make the program most readable, we would mean to startg with 1, not zero. That's what even OP has done. So either we translate or ignore 0 element. Which is what I meant by explicitly initializing the array to be 1-based. The *initialize* wasn't the best word of selection here - I realized.

Comment: If the data OP works with starts at 1, so data can be modified before referencing it to index or totally skip the first element as you mentioned. I infact like your answer the way you have explained it much clearly to OP. Cheers.

Comment: Hey @CameronSkinner : I think I got what you were trying to tell me. I was looking at the question with pre-occupied query. In the view of array out of bound/like OP indexed past the array bounds. However the culprit was the **other possible cause -> making sure object references are not null before accessing.** Thank you :)